# Robust regression (Passing-Pablok) with more than 50% of the points on the coordinate(0,0)

Tags: regression, robust

I have an issue with a regression problem. Indeed, I need to fit a linear regression on this data. **The problem is more than 50% of the data points are located in the origin (0,0) of the graph** (because the experience produces a lot of points in this specific location). I have shown the histogram of X.

It is for medical publication. In our field, everyone uses the Passing-Bablok regression but it fails to be computed in this case (indeed the slope is equal to 0).

[image]

I can't use the Deming regression because my data is unfortunately not normal.

The classical linear regression is not accepted either because it is not a "robust regression".

Thank you very much

Have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

in principle, PB regression should also work if there are many points in the origin. Are their coordinates all exactly (0,0)? Which program did you use? In R, you could use the mcr package from CRAN, which has several options to perform PB regression.

Kind regards
Florian